# connecting to server on one machine from another on same wifi network

Tags: wireless-networking

Probably a simple task, but not so simple for me.

I am running a parse server deployed locally on my laptop.

When i run an software from my laptop with connection string http://localhost:1337/parse it works fine. When i run the software on my another device in same wifi network, obviously localhost does not work.

Laptop with server is on ubuntu.

How do i connect from the other device to my laptop's server?

Comment: Replace `localhost` with the server IP address?

Comment: @DavidPostill doesnt work.